# Send .mobileconfig file via SMS OTA

Tags: iphone

I have a iPhone configuration profile (.mobileconfig) hosted on a server. The users are able to download and install it with ease. The problem arises when the users are unable to connect to internet (due to any reason) and download the file.

I was wondering if we could send the configuration profile through an SMS OTA - which has the profile and not the download link. The user opens the SMS, which in turn opens the Profile installation UI.

Any suggestion will be helpful. A way to build some "iPhone Configuration" app consisting of locally saved configuration profiles will be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the same idea as you.

It is possible. You send to send the .mobileconfig file via SMS which can be done by attaching the file using a SMS utility via outlook or via a webpage.

I just took the file which the apple utility, XML and produced the same output.

I decided to build a proof of concept page, here iconfig.kryptos.co.uk and let me know you thoughts..

Thanks, Wayne

Comment: I tried using the URL and got the error <<Could not find a part of the path 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\config\tc3ieufd.55z.mobileconfig'.>>

Also I think you generate a URL of the .mobileconfig which needs to be downloaded on to the device. But I've clearly stated in the question that the user may not be connected to internet. So download isn't possible.

Comment: Right OK.   Thanks for the feedback..   If you enter the mobile number it will send the mobileconfig file via text/sms.   I shall look into the above error.

Comment: Sahil,  I have just noted that you say the user may not be connected to the internet, won't they have 3g/4g?

Comment: Dose anyone found a solution for  this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually sending SMS configuration settings is a bit different than real use case of OTA messages. OTA addresses transfering secure data using SMS or IP bearer between sending entity and SIM module such as new SMS center address update.

It is totally vendor specific area and you need to know toolkit application reference, minimum security level settings, OTA Keys (KiC & KiD) of SIM card and some other parameters such as SPI-1 and SPI-2 bytes to prepare secure data envelope as SMPP message.

Configuration settings are actually binary SMS using 8 bit data coding scheme and esm class UDH mask without encryption with OTA keys and cryptographic checksum. Short message field of submit sm consists of UDH header and followed by configuration data for device.